# How to poll my google mail inbox for mails using Apache Camel?

Tags: java, gmail, apache-camel, polling

I am trying to learn how to use Apache Camel and currently I want to try to poll my Google mail inbox for mails.

To do so, I first tried the following sample provided in Apache Camel's documentation for the Mail component:

```
from("imaps://imap.gmail.com?username=YOUR_USERNAME@gmail.com&password=YOUR_PASSWORD"
    + "&delete=false&unseen=true&consumer.delay=60000").to("log:newmail");
```

This is my code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    // create CamelContext
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

    // add our route to the CamelContext
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder()
    {
        public void configure()
        {
            from("imap://imap.gmail.com?username=YOUR_USERNAME@gmail.com&password=YOUR_PASSWORD"
                + "&delete=false&unseen=true&consumer.delay=10000").to("log:newmail");
        }
    });

    // start the route and let it do its work
    context.start();
    Thread.sleep(60000);

    // stop the CamelContext
    context.stop();
}
```

After having put my username and correct password in the appropriate fields, I ran the compilation and execution of my code using maven :

```
mvn clean compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=natan.apps.ApacheCamelDemo
```

I get the following in my console :

```
[ead #0 - imap://imap.gmail.com] MailConsumer                   DEBUG Connecting to MailStore: imap://imap.gmail.com:143, folder=INBOX
[ead #0 - imap://imap.gmail.com] MailConsumer                   WARN  Consumer Consumer[imap://imap.gmail.com?consumer.delay=10000&delete=false&password=xxxxxx&unseen=true&username=natan.daniel0%40gmail.com] failed polling endpoint: imap://imap.gmail.com?consumer.delay=10000&delete=false&password=xxxxxx&unseen=true&username=natan.daniel0%40gmail.com. Will try again at next poll. Caused by: [javax.mail.MessagingException - * BYE Cannot connect to IMAP server ::ffff:64.233.166.108 (::ffff:64.233.166.108:143), connect error 10060]
javax.mail.MessagingException: * BYE Cannot connect to IMAP server ::ffff:64.233.166.108 (::ffff:64.233.166.108:143), connect error 10060;
  nested exception is:
        com.sun.mail.iap.ConnectionException: * BYE Cannot connect to IMAP server ::ffff:64.233.166.108 (::ffff:64.233.166.108:143), connect error 10060
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:723)[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)[javax.mail-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
        at org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailConsumer.ensureIsConnected(MailConsumer.java:520)[camel-mail-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailConsumer.poll(MailConsumer.java:94)[camel-mail-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:175)[camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:102)[camel-core-2.18.2.jar:2.18.2]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)[:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)[:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)[:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)[:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)[:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)[:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_111]
```

I cannot connect to the IMAP server.

Is there something missing in my code ? Do I need some SSL configuration ? Note that I have simply enabled IMAP in my Google mail settings.

I am using maven to handle dependencies and Eclipse to edit my code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to turn on imap in your google mail account to allow accessing your emails. By default it does not allow that.

Comment: Hello M. Ibsen, thank you for your answer. Actually imap was by default activated in my Google mail account settings. Only pop was disabled.

Comment: No other suggestions ?

Comment: Its some network error you get with that connect error code 10060. Try from another network, like your home internet connect and not a company network which may have all kind of firewall rules/issues

Comment: Yip agreed sounds like a network error, can you create a normal imap connection outside of the camel context.

Comment: Sorry this is a bit late, but you have used: "imap://..." but the documentation you have quoted shows "imaps://...".  I believe Google requires SSL.